# php mysql sum amount of table2 and group by table one's field

Tags: php, mysql

i want to sum amount from sale table and want to group it by brand, can anyone help me to right query of php mysql.

```
--- product ---

id  pcode   pname   brand
1   123     Dalda   1
2   124     Habib   1
3   125     Sufi    2
4   126     Toyota  3



--- sale ---
id  pcode   pname   amount
1   123     Dalda   1020
2   123     Dalda   1020
3   124     Habib   1030
4   124     Habib   1030
5   125     Sufi    1040
6   125     Sufi    1040
7   126     Toyota  1050
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.brand, sum(s.amount)
FROM product p
INNER JOIN sale s on s.pcode = p.pcode
GROUP BY p.brand
```

You will get only brands with an entry in sales table.

if you want all the brands, even without an entry in sale table, then use a `LEFT JOIN` and

```
COALESCE(SUM(amount, 0))
```

By the way, as pointed by Mahmoud Gamal, you don't need the pname in table Sale. I wouldn't use pcode as "relation column" also, but use product id. So you may remove pcode and pname and use a new column p_id, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  p.pname,
  IFNULL(SUM(amount), 0) AS TotalAmount
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN sale s ON p.pcode = s.pcode
GROUP BY p.pname;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb67a/1)

This will give you:

```
|  PNAME | TOTALAMOUNT |
------------------------
|  Dalda |        2040 |
|  Habib |        2060 |
|   Sufi |        2080 |
| Toyota |        1050 |
```

**Note that:** There is no need to store the `pname` in the second table `Sale`. Remove it since it is already stored in the first table `Product`.

Comment: I think pname is a product name, not the brand name. So this will group by product name, not brand.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus But the `pcode |  pname` values in the `sale` are the same as the `pcode  |  pname` values in the `product` table? Thats why I assumed they are the same.

Comment: they are the same "product" but not the same "brand" (see table product, line 1 and 2 : 2 products : 2 pcode, 2 pname, 1 brand).

Answer (score 0):

```
select pr.pcode,pr.pname,pr.brand,sum(s.amount)
from product pr
left join sale s
on pr.pcode=s.pcode
group by pr.pcode,pr.pname,pr.brand
```